# How to use the gmap module withouth a API key?

Tags: google-maps

I use [gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) module to show maps in a website. This module require an API key from google maps. But today I found this page http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/maps/signup.html when I try to generate a new API key which says:

> The API keys generated by this page are no longer available.

**But the [gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) module still require it:**
[image: capture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [suggested](http://drupal.org/node/1444762) in the issue someone opened for the GMap project page, head to [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#api_key) and follow the steps to obtain a key (Google account required).